# c evaluation order

Tags: c, operator-precedence

let's assume I have the followin code

```
#define CHECK(result) do{                         \
                          if(result == 0)         \
                                 return false;    \
                           } while(0)


int sum(int a, int b){

    return (a + b);
}

int main(){
   int a = b = 0;
   CHECK(sum(a + b));
   reutnr 0;
}
```

my question is what is an order of evaluation in C, I mean:

```
result = sum(a, b) 
//and only after checking              
if(result == 0)         
   return false;
```

or

```
if(sum(a + b) == 0)         
   return false;
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The macro substitution will be done before the actual compiler even sees the code, so the code that is compiled will read

```
int main(){
  int a = b = 0;
  do {
    if(sum(a+b) == 0)
     return false;
  } while(0);
  reutnr 0;
}
```

There will never be a variable called `result`.

Also note that C does not have a keyword called `false`.

Comment: C99 has macros true, false defined as 1, 0. But you right that it is a bad practice to use true, false in plain C.

Comment: Especially here, where an int is expected and `false == 0 == EXIT_SUCCESS`.

Answer (score 0):

C macros are plain text substitutions. The compiler will see exactly:

```
do {
  if(sum(a + b) == 0)
    return false;
} while(0);
```

Your macro does not "generate" a `result` variable.